# Creating an R environment using anaconda

Tags: r, anaconda, conda

I want to create a new R environment using anaconda. Following this page 'https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-r-language/' I created an environment called eeEnv_r using this command in anaconda prompt `conda create -n r_env r-essentials r-base`. However the environment that was created looks like it was python environment. But when I type `conda list` I see some r packages such as dplyr appearing in addition to some python packages. Also there is python.exe file in environment folder. Any ideas why this is ?

I am trying to use VS code to run R, since I am familier with the IDE (used for python work). Also I want to create environments in R and then use those environment ins VS code (similar to python).

Comment: You can do `conda create --no-default-packages -n r_env r-base r-essentials` and it will leave out most of the default python packages. Your environment will still contain a `python.exe` though. But that doesn't matter. You can still run `R` and keep your packages in your environment.

Comment: By any chance do you know if Jupyter in vs code can run R similar to the web Jupyter ?

Answer (score 1):

`r-base` depends on ``` glib``notebook ```, which depends on python, therefore installing the latest r-base package will always pull in a python interpreter as well.

I would look at this from a different angle: with conda there is no such thing as a `python` or `r`-environment environments can mix packages from various languages. For most use cases this should not be a problem.

Comment: Tried that, too, but you still get a python.exe in your environment.

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen, hmh - I should have tested this... It looks like r-base depends on glib, which in turn depends on python. So the latest r-base conda package will always come with python.